# Passing certain values of a matrix usi a logical mask

Tags: matlab, indices

Assum I have a matrix of logicals `MxN`:

```
mask=[0 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0];
```

in this case M=N=5.
A second matrix `A` with the sizes 'MxNx3' (RGB image). I want to pass a function values of `A` with respect to the mask. For example all values that are not part of the mask:

```
   foo(A(~mask));
```

Sure this line of code is useless since `mask` gives me indices of only one of the RGB colors.

- what is the correct way to do this?
- Can I get away with a one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repmat` to repeat your mask 3 times in the third dimension. This will create a `nnz(~mask) * 3` element vector. You can reshape the result of the `repmat` operation such that the rows are the `true` elements in your mask and the columns are the third dimension

```
foo(reshape(A(~repmat(mask, [1 1 3])), [], 3))
```

You could also do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656010/3d-matrix-how-to-use-row-column-pairs-with-3rd-dimension-wildcard-in-matlab/42656125#42656125) to accomplish something similar.